# wxpython Update panel new items

Tags: wxpython

Dear wxPython experts,

I am a newbie in wxPython...

I try to change a panel content according to wx.ListCtrl entries. It does not work perfectly : at the change, the panel content is overlapped by the previous content, and I would like to clear the panel before inserting the new content.

Who could help me to understand my mistake ?

Thanks a lot,

Rémy

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class MainProcesses(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(500, 300) )
        self.parent = parent
        mainSZ = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(mainSZ)
        self.Layout()
        mainSZ.Clear(True)

        A_h = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Heading:")
        A_t = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "")
        A_sb = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Simulate")
        A_cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "Water" )
        A_cb11 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "Vapor")
        A_cb12 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "Snow")

        A_cb2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "Transport")
        A_rb21 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "Standard")
        A_rb22 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "Major")
        A_rb23 = wx.RadioButton(self, -1, "Evaluated")

        A_cb3 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "Heat transport")
        A_cb4 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "water uptake")
        A_cb5 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "Growth")
        A_cb6 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, "CO2 transport")            


        bs_t = wx.StaticBoxSizer(A_h, wx.VERTICAL)
        bs_t.Add(A_t, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        sbSZ = wx.StaticBoxSizer(A_sb, wx.VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb1, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb11, 0, wx.LEFT, 20)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb12, 0, wx.LEFT, 20)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb2, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)
        sbSZ.Add(A_rb21, 0, wx.LEFT, 20)
        sbSZ.Add(A_rb22, 0, wx.LEFT, 20)
        sbSZ.Add(A_rb23, 0, wx.LEFT, 20)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb3, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb4, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb5, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)
        sbSZ.Add(A_cb6, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)

        mainSZ.Add(bs_t, wx.CENTER|wx.EXPAND, 3)
        mainSZ.Add(sbSZ, 0, wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, 3)

        self.Layout()


class GeometryInfo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(500, 300) )
        self.parent = parent
        #print self.parent.GetSize()
        mainSZ = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(mainSZ)
        self.Layout()
        mainSZ.Clear(True)

        B_sb1 = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Length units", size=(100,-1))
        B_rb21 = wx.RadioButton(self, 0, "mm")
        B_rb22 = wx.RadioButton(self, 0, "cm")
        B_rb23 = wx.RadioButton(self, 0, "m")

        B_sb2 = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "")
        B_NbSoilMat = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "1")
        B_NbLayers = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "1")
        B_h1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Nomber of materials")
        B_h2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Number of layers ")

        sbSZ1 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(B_sb1, wx.VERTICAL)
        sbSZ1.Add(B_rb21, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sbSZ1.Add(B_rb22, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sbSZ1.Add(B_rb23, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sbSZ2 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(B_sb2, wx.VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        sbSZ21 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        sbSZ21.Add(B_NbSoilMat, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
        sbSZ21.Add(B_h1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)     

        sbSZ22 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        sbSZ22.Add(B_NbLayers, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
        sbSZ22.Add(B_h2, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        sbSZ2.Add(sbSZ21, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sbSZ2.Add(sbSZ22, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        mainSZ.Add(sbSZ1, 0, wx.ALL, 15)
        mainSZ.Add(sbSZ2, 0, wx.ALL, 15)

        self.Layout()


# #####################################################################################################################        
Configs = ['Main processes', 'Geometry']

class ListCtrlLeft(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_NO_HEADER | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        image = 'images/java.png'

        self.parent = parent

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnSelect)

        self.il = wx.ImageList(32,32)

        self.il.Add(wx.Bitmap(image))

        self.SetImageList(self.il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
        self.InsertColumn(0, '')
        L = len (Configs)
        for i in range ( L ):
            self.InsertStringItem(0, Configs[L-i-1])
            self.SetItemImage(0, 0)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        size = self.parent.GetSize()
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, size.x-5)
        event.Skip()

    def OnSelect(self, event):
        window = self.parent.GetGrandParent().FindWindowByName('PanelControlOnRight')
        index = event.GetIndex()
        window.LoadData(index)

    def OnFocus(self, event):
        self.SetItemBackgroundColour(0, 'red')

class PanelMainProcess(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        event.Skip()   

    def LoadData(self, index):        
        mainSZ = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainSZ.Layout()        

        if index == 0:            
            self.p = MainProcesses(self.parent)
            mainSZ.Add( self.p )

        elif index==1:
            self.geoinfo = GeometryInfo(self.parent)
            mainSZ.Add( self.geoinfo )      
        else:
            print "Index not found"

        self.SetSizer(mainSZ)
        mainSZ.Fit(self)
        mainSZ.Layout()

class MyFrame(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        self.mainbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1, style=wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE|wx.SP_NOBORDER)
        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1 )

        panel12 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        list1 = ListCtrlLeft(panel12, -1)

        vbox.Add(list1, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        panel12.SetSizer(vbox)
        #panel12.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')

        vbox1.Add(panel12, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        panel1.SetSizer(vbox1)

        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(splitter, -1)

        panel22 = wx.Panel(panel2, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        vbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.Main = PanelMainProcess(panel22)
        self.Main.SetName('PanelControlOnRight')

        vbox3.Add(self.Main, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel22.SetSizer(vbox3)

        panel22.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')
        vbox2.Add(panel22, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        panel2.SetSizer(vbox2)
        panel2.SetAutoLayout(True)

        vbox2.Fit(self)

        splitter.SplitVertically(panel1, panel2)

        hbox.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, 5)

        hhbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        bOk = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "Ok")

        hhbox.AddStretchSpacer(100)
        hhbox.Add(bOk, 0, wx.RIGHT,5)

        self.mainbox.Add(hbox, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.mainbox.Add(hhbox, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 10)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainbox)

        self.SetSize( (1200,500) )

        bOk.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOk)

    def OnOk(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        f = MyFrame(None, -1, "Title")
        f.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(f)
        return True

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You don't _have to_ format your question like a letter :)

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that...

Comment: I am not actually seeing any data loaded, so I can't reproduce the problem. I suspect you are just missing a call to `Layout` somewhere though.

Comment: It is strange. I can see the layout on the right panel when clicking on an item of the list.

Comment: One way to catch and understand problems is to simplify the code to the [minimal working lines of code reproducing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This also help others to help you